# nested tableview with automatic dimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a `TableView` that its cell contains a second `TableView` (Nested `TableView`).
Inner tableView shows comments that have variable cell height. Calculate this height with `UITableView.automaticDimension`.
But main tableView  cannot calculate it's cell height properly.
Main tableView use `UITableView.automaticDimension` for calculating cell height. but innerTableView doesn't show in the main tableView.

Comment: don't do nesting, it's really hard, use single tableview with multiple section

Comment: if possible: provide your expected ui

Comment: My test project share in comments of next answer.

Comment: if use section instead of Nested TableView, my viewController will be Massive because my tableView has 19 sections!

Comment: @SPatel Download sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/woieoi71t5kt66d/NestedTableViewTest%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: @SPatel Can you help me?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mxdgw3sibmpe7sb/AAAPp_SGeAKjI9TUMBsK3gKba?dl=0

Answer (score -1):

My test project download link:
dropbox.com/s/woieoi71t5kt66d/NestedTableViewTest%202.zip?dl=0